# background thread in Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, worker

I'm at a loss, a simple use of swing worker.
I added  a few simple code in doInBackground(), but it does not execute, I don`t receive exceptions. When I use debuger, He is working as it should. ))
May be somebody has something like this, or make tell me ideas how to cache this mistake, or ...
Sorry, code is complex. Tell me is you need something more or comments.
if I remove "installer.setFPS(fPSCalculatorGhost.getFPS());"-string, everything will be alright.

```
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new MainWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });


public MainWindow() {
    initComponents();
}


private void initComponents() {
    InterfaceUpdateWorker interfaceUpdate = new InterfaceUpdateWorker(
            new InterfaceInfoInstallerImpl());
    interfaceUpdate.setCamera(gLEventListenerImpl.getCameraGhost());
    interfaceUpdate.setfPSCalculatorGhost(gLEventListenerImpl.getFPSCalculatorGhost());
    interfaceUpdate.execute();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException {
    while(true) {
        installer.setFPS(fPSCalculatorGhost.getFPS());
        installer.setCameraXPosition(
                cameraGhost.getCameraXPosition());
        installer.setCameraYPosition(
                cameraGhost.getCameraYPosition());
        installer.setCameraZPosition(
                cameraGhost.getCameraZPosition());
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
}
public final class FPSCalculatorGhost {

    private FPSCalculatorGhost() {
    }

    public float getFPS() {
        return fpsTask.getAvrfps();
    }
}

public float getAvrfps() {
    synchronized (this) {
    return avrfps;
    }
}
```

Everything revolves around fpsTask-object. It is used by interfaceUpdate-thread (or application worker thread) and it is used by other thread, where it is initialized.
Outcome:
1). fpsTask-object is initialized in one thread
2). fpsTask-object gives values to another thread.

When I make fpsTask from FPSCalculatorGhost final, it begin to work.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: Agrees with Romain -- how can we guess what your mistake is if you hide the code from us?

Comment: I don t understand when I make fpsTask final, it begin to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is the `installer.setFPS(fPSCalculatorGhost.getFPS());` line. What does it do?
It calls the `getAvrFPS` method, and this contains this block:

```
synchronized (this) {
   return avrfps;
}
```

This `synchronized` block can only be entered when no other thread at the same time is in some synchronized block or synchronized method of the same object. In the code snippet you posted there is no such block/method, so you have to search it yourself.

Most importantly, make sure the other thread who holds the lock is not waiting on some result from this worker thread.

When you run into the deadlock, run `jstack` with the process-ID of your java process to get stack traces of all threads running - this includes the locks they are holding and waiting on. (`jps` gives you all java process IDs.)

Comment: I check, this synchronized block does not influence.

Comment: How I said, the worker tread does not execute when I add "installer.setFPS(fPSCalculatorGhost.getFPS());"-string. doInBackground() function is not called and that is it.

Comment: @itun: From your source snippet this single synchronized block there is the sole probable reason - if we should be able to help more, we need more context. (For example, the `setFPS` method.)

Comment: Could you please build a short example showing only your problem? From the above code snippets I am only guessing which method is where. I think like others that the problem must be in the synchronization. BTW building a simple example is a very useful task it helps you to isolate a problem better.